# Python Beautiful Soup extracting data within a div tag itself

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to use Pythons beautifulSoup to pull data from an HTML file. The following line of HTML is the one I'm interested in.

```
<div class="myself" title="Name@email.com [11:07:27 AM]">
     <nobr>Name</nobr></div>
```

I want to extract the title (with the email and time stamp). I am able to access the class with...

```
find('div', attrs={'class':'myself'}))
```

I am able to print the entire contents of the `div` from there or the info in tags within the div, but I can't figure out how to get the `title` because it's within the same `div` tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Attributes can be retrieved in a dictionary-like manner](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

> A tag may have any number of attributes. You can access a tag’s
>   attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
div = soup.find("div", class_="myself", title=True)
print(div["title"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use may this method

```
>>>import bs4
>>>html_string = "<div class="myself" title="Name@email.com [11:07:27 AM]">
 <nobr>Name</nobr></div>"
>>>title_string = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_string).div.attrs['title']
>>>print(title_string)
'Name@email.com [11:07:27 AM]'
```

Comment: It is correct. For  <div>html_string</div> just add one more div: title_string = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_string).div.div.attrs['title']. For html_string_1, html_string_2 you have to loop.

Comment: I mean if you had `<div>Hello</div><div class=“myself” title=“name@email.com”></div>` Then it won’t work this way. In general, doing `soup.<tag_name>` will get the first tag in the tree.